# How to batch extract images from a PDF

Tags: pdf, batch-processing, image-extraction

**TL/DR Version:**
 How do I extract the image out of the Type B file below. Note that there are around 600 such files so I would prefer some sort of batch operation.

[Type A](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a45a1g9vy89zc1w/Type%20A.pdf) 
[Type B](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kc6uusw0bdrg6t7/Type%20B.pdf)

**Details:**
 I'm redesigning my company's online catalog an need top extract the design images from ~2000 PDFs which either Type A (where I can export the images using Acrobat XI *Tools - Document Processing - Extract All Images*) or of Type B.

I don't know how these were designed or the cause for the difference (the PDF creation was contracted out to some now defunct company 2 yrs ago).

As noted above I can batch process (Acrobat XI *Action Wizard*) all Type A files but that still leaves me with ~600 Type B files for which I am clueless.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `pdfimages` (poppler utils):

http://cgit.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/tree/utils

Comment: Whoops! Forgot to mention : I'm working on Windows and have no experience in Linux.